# Delete link with hash compare to mysql cell

Tags: php, mysql, hash

I want a user to be able to delete his reservation time from link by giving him a direct link with hash for ex.

http://example.org/delete.php?=a8df5b232f5ed38c9574ecbd0c248feccc968e83

I want to make this hash (a8df5b232f5ed38c9574ecbd0c248feccc968e83) be compared to this one added to dB (to this order) and if they match record is removed.

Here is code that I do for generating a hash and adding it to my dB

```
$createDeleteHash = $getLastId['id'] . $nazwisko;
$deleteHash = sha1($createDeleteHash);
$stmt3 = $db->exec("UPDATE `order` SET delete_hash='$deleteHash' WHERE id='$getLastId[id]'");
```

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: What exactly do you need? To know how to search the DB for the string and delete it? If so `DELETE FROM order WHERE delete_hash = "a8df5b232f5ed38c9574ecbd0c248feccc968e83"`

Comment: I want to compare GET parameter in link with cell in db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to change the url you are sending from:

```
http://example.org/delete.php?=a8df5b232f5ed38c9574ecbd0c248feccc968e83
```

To the following

```
http://example.org/delete.php?id=a8df5b232f5ed38c9574ecbd0c248feccc968e83
```

Notice the `id` preceding the hash. This allows you to grab the GET variable using `$_GET['id']`.

So on your delet.php page, you then need somehting like so:

```
$sql="DELETE FROM order WHERE delete_hash = ':hash'";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindParam(':hash', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);

$sth->execute();
```

This will then delete the hash from the table. So you probably want to wrap the execute in an if so that you can send a message on the page, ie deleted or not deleted etc.

Comment: I did all you say and it's not removing row with that hash.

Comment: $sql = "DELETE FROM `order` WHERE delete_hash='$_GET[id]'";
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

That solved my problem.